# Why do airlines not paint the wings on their livery? Why?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, airlines, livery

Does anyone know why airlines do not paint the wings on their aircraft? What is the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Some do. However, paint is expensive and heavy. You may find that getting approval to paint a lift producing surface is more difficult to justify to the regulatory authorities. And also, why paint somewhere you can't see very well when it adds weight and therefore burn more fuel?